# Incorrect value when casting value from varchar to float

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I have a strange issue. I need to push data from Staging to destination.

I have field lets say "`sample_cost Varchar (10)`" destination column "`sample_cost Float"`. Example value lets say `87876` (in source)

I wrote a query

```
select cast(sample_cost as float)/100 from source_table
```

result = `878.76`  which is right.

But when I run the job using simple Data Flow in SSIS I am getting result as `878.7`

I tried casting using Decimal, Money  from source but same issue.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Comment: What is the datatype in the destination table?

Comment: What happens, if you just write `CAST(sample_cost as int)` (without the `/100`)? How do you detect, that the last decimal is missing? Might be, that everything is correct, but your presentation tool does some rounding / trunctation...

Comment: @Shnugo. I am using SQL server. And I am using SSIS to transfer data from Staging to Destination table. (SQL Server 2008) . As I said the staging table has 87876 which when I select I am getting right value its happening when I insert data to destination

Comment: Show code and structure of destination table...

Comment: destination is float,null. I guess I got the work around If I do directly in SQL Server then I am getting it right

Comment: insert into destination table select cast(sample_cost as float)/100 from source_table

Comment: Why are you doing this in a data flow???    Do I understand correctly that you are using a dataflow task just to perform an INSERT..SELECT operation?   What are the components in your dataflow?

Comment: In your data flow, go to advanced properties of the source. Go to output tab and see the data type and length of the column "sample_cost". I suspect the length is incorrect in the output of the source component.